# Trouble installing RMagick on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rmagick, magickwand

Whenever I try to install the rmagick gem using sudo gem install rmagick the install fails when it tries to include a header file called wand/MagicWand.h

The exact error from the log file is:

```
gcc -E -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I.  -I$MAGICK_HOME/include/ImageMagick  -I/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:1:29: error: wand/MagickWand.h: No such file or directory
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include <wand/MagickWand.h>
/* end */
```

The $MAGICK_HOME env variable is set to `/usr/bin/imagemagick`
The header file it is looking for is located in `/usr/bin/imagemagick/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h`

I was trying to follow the instructions found [here](http://jaredonline.posterous.com/installing-imagemagick-on-snowleopard-106). I am installing this on an Intel iMac running Snow Leopard.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use brew instead of macports. https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew there is info on how to install brew and then you can install imagemagick by using `brew install imagemagick`. Read the wiki to see how to clear out macport installations.

Comment: +1 homebrew solved all of my problems with installing ImageMagick on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Homebrew actually solved my problem. Thanks a lot sorens.

Comment: @sorens: Can you post your comment as an answer so we can upvote it and get this question off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Comment: sure thing. see answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use [Brew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) instead of macports. There is information on how to install brew and then you can install imagemagick by using the command `brew install imagemagick`. Read the wiki to see how to clear out macport installations.

Comment: FWIW, a brew install of imagemagick wasn't enough for me.  I also had to brew install pkg-config, otherwise doing a gem install of rmagick would bail.